# Updating the GridView inside the ViewPager using the PagerAdapter

Tags: android, gridview, android-pageradapter

I have used GridView inside the ViewPager, and when I try to update the GridView using the gridViewAdapter.notifydatasetchanged(), it doesn't updates. But when I scroll through all the pages and comes back to the original page, it shows the updated view. Im cluless, please help me someone how to deal with this.

I don't want to use the viewPager.notifydatsetchanged() as it reloads all the page items.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "FTICKERS";
            case 1:
                return "QUOTES";
            case 2:
                return "MEMES";
            case 3:
                return "MOVIES";
        }

        return null;
    }

    Context activity;


    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context act) {

        activity = act;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        //return super.getItemPosition(object);
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, final int position) {


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        Context context = cont;



        view0 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_f, null);

        //send=view0;
        gridview0 = (GridView) view0.findViewById(R.id.gridview_stickers_f);
        imageAdapter0 = new ImageAdapter(context,"fticker");
        gridview0.setAdapter(imageAdapter0);

        view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quotes, null);

        //send=view0;
        gridview1 = (GridView) view1.findViewById(R.id.gridview_stickers_quotes);
        imageAdapter1 = new ImageAdapter(context,"quotes");
        gridview1.setAdapter(imageAdapter1);

        view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_memes, null);

        //send=view0;
        gridview2 = (GridView) view2.findViewById(R.id.gridview_stickers_memes);
        imageAdapter2 = new ImageAdapter(context,"memes");
        gridview2.setAdapter(imageAdapter2);

        view3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, null);

        //send=view0;
        gridview3 = (GridView) view3.findViewById(R.id.gridview_stickers_movies);
        imageAdapter3 = new ImageAdapter(context,"movies");
        gridview3.setAdapter(imageAdapter3);


        if(position==0)
        {

            send=view0;
            folder="fticker";
            Log.e("Folder Name is::",folder);

            urlSet = new HashSet<String>();
            imgUri = new HashSet<Uri>();
            imgName = new HashSet<String>();


            display = dialog.getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            metrics = new DisplayMetrics();


            if(instFlag0==0) {
                addDatatoAdapter(pg, null, "fticker");
                instFlag0=1;
                //Toast.makeText(cont,"Hola", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            gridview0.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
                private int currentVisibleItemCount;
                private int currentScrollState;
                private int currentFirstVisibleItem;
                private int totalItem;
                private LinearLayout lBelow;


                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    this.currentScrollState = scrollState;
                    this.isScrollCompleted();
                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                     int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    this.currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
                    this.currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
                    this.totalItem = totalItemCount;


                }

                private void isScrollCompleted() {
                    if (totalItem - currentFirstVisibleItem == currentVisibleItemCount
                            && this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                        /** To do code here*/
                        //Toast.makeText(cont, "Scrolled down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Toast.makeText(cont, "0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        pg++;
                        addDatatoAdapter(pg, null, "fticker");
                        //viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }
            });

            gridview0.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                        int position, long id) {

                    ChatWidgetService.onShare(imageAdapter0.getUri(position));


                }
            });

            gridview0.setTag(0);
            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view0, 0);
            return view0;

        }
```

Comment: Please, post some code so far: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: above is the code for PagerAdapter class.